# Giving multiple rooms wired internet access

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, home-networking

The idea is that I want to give wired internet access (Ethernet) to every room in my house, using the cables already routed in the walls (Cat5 cables). Because the cables are already routed, the only task left is to connect everything together.

The house has a "crawl space" beneath (don't know the if that is the correct word for it in English, but it's basically a space under the house where all the cables and pipes are laid).

The router stands in the "office". I would like to plug only one of the outgoing Ethernet connections on it into the wall, and then branch the connection so that I can draw a cable to each room.

Is the best way then to put a switch just after the Ethernet socket in the wall, down in the "crawl space", then draw each of the output-cables from it to each room, or is there a cleaner, or more elegant solution?

Comment: Wireless might be the faster, cheaper, easier choice.  If your cat5 is plain cat5, then wireless 802.11n will be faster.

Comment: @Keltari I probably should have mentioned wireless is not an option, because some devices require wire.

Comment: @Keltari Wireless is NEVER faster than wire (unless you are dredging up incredibly slow old wired equipment as a stalking horse.) Gigabit ethernet consistently trounces "1300 mbit" 802.11(ac) which is a marketing number that's 1: half-duplex and 2: combining best possible throughput of two bands that no end-use device combines. Gigabit ethernet is full duplex...

Comment: @Ecnerwal 802.11n is faster that fast ethernet by 3 times, which he would be limited to by plain cat5 cable.

Comment: @Keltari - that, also, is a half-duplex, and counting all the WiFi overhead (not actual data you're moving) as part of the bits number. I can beat "300 MBit 802.11n" 25 hours a day, 8 days a week with a full-duplex fast ethernet wire. Not that I've bothered with one of those in a decade or more since gigabit ethernet became commonly available. 90MBit actual throughput is a good day for 802.11n. The odds that the cable is cat5 rather than 5e are vanishingly small unless the cable is more than 20 years old (and most Cat5 cable will pass 5e if tested)

Comment: Where do all the cables terminate? One end would be in say the room with the router but where is the other end?  Same for all the other cables.  That will determine your install options.

Comment: The Ethernet switch (which requires power) should be accessible (and indoors in a "normal" environment), rather than in the crawl space.  That's the typical purpose of an "equipment closet", where cable runs to every room would terminate and connect to a switch.

Comment: @DaveM I need an "output socket" in each room, so I guess I need one cable to terminate in each room, if you can't do some kind of "series connection" (sorry for the lack of English terms, I'm from Sweden :))

Comment: Your terms are fine, perfectly understandable. You can't do a series connection (unless you put a small switch there, and it's in many ways better to just have one switch that's big enough for the whole house.)

Comment: Have you considered [Ethernet over Power]( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication)?

Comment: @tonysdg In fact that is what I'm using right now, but just as a "temporary" solution, though I've experienced some small problems with it, and also it just feels more "permanent" to get rid of them, and use the already drawn cables in the walls. In whichever case, Ethernet over Power is neither an alternative, though it might be a great solution for some. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Somewhere, those ethernet cables terminate, besides in each room. Each cable from each room must have another end, and, likely, they all end in the same place (such as a closet). That is where the switch should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Using a switch would be the best option; I don't think there's a tidier way other than wireless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dedicated to "neatness" over survivability, a switch in the crawl-space will do that. It's a lousy place for a switch, though - crawl spaces tend to be not as clean and dry as an inside location, so the odds of having a switch fail are greatly increased by locating it there, .vs. an inside location.

You might treat it as though it were outside, and put the switch into a weatherproof (or at least dust-proof) box.

Alternate solution is to have the switch inside, and have all the other cables come up to where it is, inside. Some spot in a storage closet (out of sight most of the time) is a typical location.

Actually, I suppose it **is** possible that we are getting hung up on a connotation that may not apply due to nuance in the language. A "crawl space" is typically one in which you literally need to crawl (a meter or sometimes less high) and often dirt-floored as well. A "basement" is in the same position relative to the house but you can generally stand up in it (2 meters or a little more), and it's more likely to be suitable for putting a switch in.

Comment: If you do put the ethernet switch in an inaccessible location at least put a power switch for it somewhere accessible. Cheap ethernet switches crash from time to time and need a powercycle.

Comment: @Ecnerwal In this case, the definition of "crawl space" is very similar to the first of your "alternatives". It is about a meter high and is dirt-floored.

Comment: @plugwash I've thought about that, and I think the simplest way would be to connect the switch to its own separate circuit, then put a switch ("circuit breaker", to separate it from the term "switch") on that circuit somewhere in the house. Would that be enough?